# Page reloads empty using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I created an application in  static HTML, and now I had an idea:

Use a wordpress plugin that transform wordpress pages into JSON objects (titles, subtitles, content, dates, etc), then i could pull the content in my static html application using ajax = the WP becomes my CMS.

Ok, it's working, is showing the information, but now comes the real problem:

The ajax is trigger every time the user clicks on the landing page in the menu, for example:

1 - The user clicks on "About Us" in the menu.
2 - Ajax is trigger and pulls the information from the page "About Us" in Wordpress
3 - The content is displayed in html.

**PROBLEM**: If the user reload the pages, the content will not show anymore.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a page reload to bring back the exact same dynamically constructed content you had, then you have to do two things:

1. Whenever you dynamically modify the page, you have to update the URL (in a way that doesn't reload the page) so that the URL contains enough information to convey to your code what the state of the page is.
2. When your page loads, you must look at the parameters in the URL and rebuild the desired page as part of the page initialization.

One common way to do this is to use a hash tag in the URL (e.g. information after the `#`) to convey the state of the page.  Then, after a reload, your page initialization code will look at the hash tag in the URL to figure out what dynamic content it should add to the page to reconstruct the page as it was.